# Cannot edit MIP-protected file on Word for Android

Tags: android, mip-sdk

I am protecting files using the File SDK with the "View", "Edit", and "Docedit" rights specified explicitly. I am then trying to edit the protected file in Microsoft Word for Android, and on Android phones I cannot edit documents. I am able to tap on the edit button, but the only key in the keyboard that seems to work is the enter key. All other typing is ignored.

Without MIP encryption, I am able to edit without any issues. Any idea what could be causing this and how I might work around it? On my Android tablet, I do not have any issue. On iOS (phones and tablets) I can edit this file. On the Android phone, I have tried copying the file to a new location using "Save As", and the issue persists. Any ideas?